# laravel email no llegan los mensajes usando un servidor compartido pero no tengo errores que me orienten

Tags: laravel, email

Estoy enviando email desde el form usando notify en servidor compartido (hostinger)
no recibo mensajes de error pero el email no llega a destino.
alguna sugerencia ?

```
 public function mailToAdmin(ContactFormRequest $message, Admin $admin)
  {        //send the admin an notification
    $admin->notify(new InboxMessage($message));
    // redirect the user back
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Gracias por Contactarse! Le responderemos a la Brevedad!');
  }
```

Comment: Agrega el código de inboxmessage y admin

Comment: https://www.bnmetrics.com/blog/simple-contact-page-tutorial-laravel-54

Comment: tome el codigo de este tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser varias cosas

Verifica si tu correo tiene permisos , en el caso de Gmail te pide desactivar el Auth2 y darle a un boton de permisos de IMAP y POP , ademas de otro boton de permitir accesos externos